# Php continues to stay crashed on server

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, crash

I've been using an Ubuntu server for about 10 months now so there is no problem with the way I set everything up. I guess I had some bad code similar to a while loop with no increasing variable to notify the while loop when to stop. And after I executed the code it did what it normally would do and freeze up until I could refresh it. But this time is different because after, it seems any .php file of mine does not show up correctly on my web browser. I can not log into my website via pulling from my phpmyadmin. I'm also not able to log into phpmyadmin. When I try to log into phpmyadmin it just refreshes the page with no error.

My question is, how can I maybe restart php in my Ubuntu server with out losing all my data in my database?

After searching things up I found another possibility for this to be happening. I believe that my hard drive on my server is full not allowing me to do anything.

How can I delete things from my server if I cannot access my database?

Comment: what about `sudo service apache2 restart`?

Comment: That did not work for it gave me "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to getting access to my database again.
The problem was that I used up pretty much all of the memory space on my virtual machine which was blocking any session at all with php. I now have access back to phpmyadmin

Step 1 - 
I cleaned up space on my virtual machine hardrive by typing all these commands:
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean

Step 2 - 
Restart virtual machine